How to get file id from a telegram bot for a file sent by the user in c#?
I'm a beginner and I just started building and developing a telegram bot. I wanted to download the files user sends to the bot in c#, but actually I need a file id to download that. I've surfed the internet for hours but I can't find a solution.
I tried different ways but I failed.

I suppose you're using the Telegram.Bot library to build Telegram Bot with C#. You may please share the current code you have - this will help in a better solution.
Anyway, when a file is sent to the Bot by the user, you will receive a Update with Message property filled. If the file is sent as a Document, the Message.Document property will be not null and you can get the File ID as the following code:
var fileId = update.Message.Document.FileId;

// Now you can download the file with this identifier

Upon checking the library documentation, I could see they have DownloadFileAsync request to actually download the file out-of-the-box.
const string destinationFilePath = "../downloaded.file";

await using Stream fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(destinationFilePath);
var file = await botClient.GetInfoAndDownloadFileAsync(fileId, fileStream);

Here's the documentation, just in case you want to refer.
Hope this helps!

Thanks. Yeah you just covered everything I needed thanks.
